# Woocommerce How to get product data to use them in custom modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a custom modal popup on the `added_to_cart` event on my `woocommerce`-shop page which indicates that a certain product has been added to the cart.

This is what I got so far:

```
$("body").on("added_to_cart", function(e, data) {
   let modalHtml = '<div id="modal" class="modal">';

    modalHtml += '<div class="modal-content">';
    modalHtml += '<div class="modal-header">';
    modalHtml += '<span class="closeBtn" id="closeBtn">&times;</span</div>';
    modalHtml += '<div class="modal-body">';
    modalHtml += "<p>PRODUCTTITLE HERE - has been added</p>";
    modalHtml += "</div>";
    modalHtml += "</div>";
    modalHtml += "</div>";

    $("body").append(modalHtml);
    $(".modal").show();

    $("#closeBtn").on("click", () => {
    $(".modal").remove();
  });
});
```

How can I get the `product_title` or the `product_data` in general and include them in the modal which is generated dynamically??

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get these values in the elements you created with jquery and then insert them in your modalHtml.
e.g. your you have the title of a product inside a div class = "productTitle"> ... , you have to type:

```
let productTitle = $(".productTitle").text(); //get the value as text.

 modalHtml += '<div class="modal-content">';
modalHtml += '<div class="modal-header">';
modalHtml += '<span class="closeBtn" id="closeBtn">&times;</span</div>';
modalHtml += '<div class="modal-body">';
modalHtml += "<p>" + productTitle + "</p>";
modalHtml += "</div>";
modalHtml += "</div>";
modalHtml += "</div>";
```

Comment: Yes, not exactly what I wanted but the idea was correct, so I accept your answer :-)